# one request to apply many changes in the DB

Tags: php, json, laravel, postman, nested-loops

i have alot of records that needs to be edited in one request, so i went for POST request
to try to edit the data in my controller like this :

```
foreach ($attr as $key){
        foreach ($key->item as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute['action'] == 'store') {
                $insert_array = [
                    'subject_quiz_id' => $key->subject_quiz_id,
                    'registration_record_id' => $attribute->registration_record_id,
                    'mark' => $attribute->mark
                ];

            }
        } }
```

and this is my postman :

```
{
"subject_quiz_id": "7",
"item": [{
        "action": "store",
        "registration_record_id": "7",
        "mark": "3"
    },
    {
        "action": "store",
        "registration_record_id": "7",
        "mark": "3"
    }]}
```

but it simply keep pushing this error:

```
    "message": "Trying to get property 'item' of non-object",
"exception": "ErrorException",
```

Comment: make sure that $attr is array/collection of objects!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$insert_array = [];
foreach ($request->all() as $item) {
            if (is_array($item)) {
                foreach ($item as $value) {
                    if (isset($value['action'], $value['registration_record_id'], $value['mark']) && $value['action'] === 'store') {
                        $insert_array[] = [
                            'subject_quiz_id' => $request->subject_quiz_id,
                            'registration_record_id' => $value['registration_record_id'],
                            'mark' => $value['mark'],
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
dd($insert_array);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code and what you have done to solve the problem.

Comment: He got an error because need a check if iterated element is array